# Method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```html
  <script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
       function compute() {
              var a = $('#a').val();
              var b = $('#b').val();
              var total = a * b + (8 / 100) * a ;
              $('#total').val(total);

            }

            $('#a, #b').change(compute);


     });
    </script>
```

¿as I can use the command (.toFixed) ?
To always display roundoff will end the sum to 2 decimal places.

Thanks.

Comment: Whats the question again?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, check out below code snippet.

```js
var a = 10;
var b = 20;
var total = a * b + (8 / 100) * a ;
alert(total.toFixed(2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ".toFixed(2)" it wil always round of to 2 decimals.
However it will return a string instead of a float/decimal number.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c3hDK/259/) `See the link for your example code to work`

Comment: Number(2.5.toFixed(2)) if need to